# List all MAC addresses and their associated IP addresses in my local network (LAN)

Tags: networking

How can I list all [MAC addresses](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MAC_address) and their associated [IP addresses](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IP_address) of the machines connected to my local network (LAN)?

Comment: it's important to understand that as soon as you go throught a level 3 network layer equipement it will not be possible to get the MAC and ip behind this equipement

Comment: `sudo tail -f /var/log/messages`, then unplug and replug in the device you're trying to find the MAC address of, or grep/read through messages to find the device.

Answer (score 78):

You can use the [Nmap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nmap) utility for this. Nmap is a free network scanner utility.

Try just:

```
sudo nmap -sn 192.168.1.0/24
```

Please substitute your network identifier and subnet mask.

**How to find a network ID and subnet mask**

Use command `ip a`:

```
bash~$ ip a
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN 
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: wlan0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP qlen 1000
    link/ether c4:85:08:94:ee:9a brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.3.66/24 brd 192.168.3.255 scope global wlan0
    inet6 fe80::c685:8ff:fe94:ee9a/64 scope link valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

Here at point 2, I have the `wlan0` device. It says `inet 192.168.3.66/24 brd 192.168.3.255 scope global wlan0`, IP address: `192.168.3.66`, subnet mask: `24`. Network ID is `192.168.3.0`, just substitute the last number by 0.

Or as `man nmap` says:

```
sudo nmap -sn 192.168.1.0/24
```

Here is a little quote from the man page, [nmap(1)](https://linux.die.net/man/1/nmap):

> ```
> -sn (No port scan)
> ```
>
> This option tells Nmap not to do a port scan after host discovery, and only print out the available hosts that responded to the scan. This is often known as a “ping scan”, but you can also request that traceroute and NSE host scripts be run.
> This is by default one step more intrusive than the list scan, and can often be used for the same purposes. It allows light reconnaissance of a target network without attracting much attention.
> Knowing how many hosts are up is more valuable to attackers than the list provided by a list scan of every single IP address and host name.
>
> Systems administrators often find this option valuable as well. It can easily be used to count available machines on a network or monitor server availability. This is
> often called a ping sweep, and is more reliable than pinging the broadcast address because many hosts do not reply to broadcast queries.
>
> The default host discovery done with **`-sn`** consists of an ICMP echo request, TCP SYN to port 443, TCP ACK to port 80, and an ICMP timestamp request by default.
> When executed by an unprivileged user, only SYN packets are sent (using a **`connect`** call) to ports 80 and 443 on the target.
> When a privileged user tries to scan targets on a local Ethernet network, ARP requests are used unless **`--send-ip`** was specified. The **`-sn`** option can be combined with any of the discovery probe types (the **`-P*`** options, excluding **`-Pn`**) for greater flexibility.
> If any of those probe type and port number options are used, the default probes are overridden. When strict firewalls are in place between the source host running Nmap and the target network, using those advanced techniques is recommended. Otherwise hosts could be missed when the firewall drops probes or their responses.
>
> In previous releases of Nmap, **`-sn`** was known as **`-sP`**.

Comment: It's not working

Comment: This will need to be adjusted so that `192.168.1.0/24` is changed to the user's IP address range.

Comment: @minerz029 Sure i did change the IP

Comment: I don't know if that is the reason, but on Linux I use `nmap -sP 192.168.1.0/24` for a ping scan.

Comment: Do you know why root priveleges  are required to read MAC addressees from the network?

Comment: You can use `192.168.1.*` rather than `192.168.1.0/24`.   I find the wildcard syntax to be much easier to understand and remember.

Answer (score 50):

**`arp`** will *slowly* return you a list of active MAC addresses and IPs or their hostnames if they have one. If you want it to go faster, you can use `arp -n` which should skip the DNS lookups. If you need to parse it into something `arp -an` will skip the fixed width columns.

```
$ arp
Address                  HWtype  HWaddress           Flags Mask            Iface
10.10.0.11               ether   00:04:ff:ff:ff:d0   C                     eth0
10.10.0.16               ether   00:04:ff:ff:ff:a6   C                     eth0
raspbmc.local            ether   00:1f:ff:ff:ff:9c   C                     eth0
10.10.0.19               ether   00:04:ff:ff:ff:c9   C                     eth0
10.10.0.12               ether   bc:f5:ff:ff:ff:93   C                     eth0
10.10.0.17               ether   00:04:ff:ff:ff:57   C                     eth0
10.10.0.1                ether   20:4e:ff:ff:ff:30   C                     eth0
HPF2257E.local           ether   a0:b3:ff:ff:ff:7e   C                     eth0
10.10.0.15               ether   00:04:ff:ff:ff:b9   C                     eth0
tim                      ether   00:22:ff:ff:ff:af   C                     eth0
10.10.0.13               ether   60:be:ff:ff:ff:e0   C                     eth0
```

Otherwise, your router should be able to give you an idea of the active devices(most do).

---

**Edit** Per davidcl's comment, this answer isn't as perfect as I'd first hoped.

`arp` relies on previous contact of some sort to work. However in my opinion modern devices are all so talkative (you should really watch wireshark — it's an education) at broadcast level that it's unlikely a device would be present on the network without at least replying to a broadcast. (To be sure you can ping all devices on the network with 10.10.0.255 first and then you will likely get 90+% of of devices.)

To give you some sort of idea of what I mean, 10.10.0.16 above is our PVR. There's no direct interaction between my PC and the PVR and there aren't any services running on the PVR (no UPNP/DLNA either).

Just to play through the arguments quickly...

- *But what about hackers in my network?!1*
  They can block ICMP pings too. They can block all responses to every
  type of scan.
- *Oh but surely `nmap` is still best possible solution*
  When run here, it's still missing out four devices. Four devices that are active on the network. Either they're not responding to the pings or nmap isn't waiting long enough for them to respond... I don't know. `nmap` is a great tool (especially for the port scanning you might want to do next) but it's still a little clumsy (and a little slow) for this problem. And don't call me Shirley.

Comment: IF I change my MAC ID with mac changer , can It show the original ?

Comment: @BYEAskUbuntu if you use MAC changer, your MAC is what you set it to be. For all network users its origin is generally unknown, so no, it can't.

Comment: @Oli do your example MAC adresses really have three 0xff bytes, or have you just hidden actual ones?

Comment: @Ruslan That's just paranoid me blanking them out... I'm sure it would be fairly hard for an individual to do anything with them but you never know who's stalking you.

Comment: I'm surprised by this answer.  "arp" does not show a list of active MAC addresses on the local network.  "arp" shows a list of MAC addresses corresponding to machines that have interacted with the machine it is being run on.  If there has been no communication between the local machine and another machine on the network recently, that machine will not show up in the "arp" listing.

Comment: @davidcl that might be true but what does interact mean? 10.10.0.16 is our PVR and there's never any active interaction between it and my PC. There must be a passive mechanism (broadcast traffic, etc) that is adding arp entries... Which would ring true for just about everything else. I've just turned our laptop on (again, no direct interaction with this computer) and it's now on the arp list. I'm not disagreeing with you, it's just modern devices are really noisy! That gets you noticed pretty quickly.

Comment: I just did a quick test on my network, and arp is displaying only about 25% of the devices that exist.  If the computer running arp hasn't received a packet from another device, it won't be on the arp list.  I'd be interested in knowing more about the devices that nmap failed to detect on your network; there are ways to hide from nmap but I've found the default nmap scan pretty effective.  That said, There's no failsafe answer because if a device isn't generating traffic and isn't answering requests, it is invisible-- but most devices will answer some type of request.

Comment: The man pages for arp declare that the program is obsolete.  The suggested replacement is `ip neighbor`, which is very fast.

Answer (score 47):

I use `arp-scan` for this:

```
$ sudo arp-scan -l
Interface: eth0, datalink type: EN10MB (Ethernet)
Starting arp-scan 1.8.1 with 256 hosts (http://www.nta-monitor.com/tools/arp-scan/)
192.168.2.1     ec:1a:59:61:07:b2       (Unknown)
192.168.2.50    90:59:af:3d:6d:bc       (Unknown)
192.168.2.51    3c:97:0e:48:22:12       (Unknown)
192.168.2.52    00:18:31:87:8f:b0       Texas Instruments

4 packets received by filter, 0 packets dropped by kernel
Ending arp-scan 1.8.1: 256 hosts scanned in 1.282 seconds (199.69 hosts/sec). 4 responded
```

Comment: If you'd like to specify the network interface, like wireless, then use this command `sudo arp-scan -l -I wlan0`

Comment: Yes, arp-scan is indeed the "best tool for the job" .

Comment: This isn't working for me... device isn't responding for some reason.

Comment: to get arp-scan to work I had to do `brew install arp-scan` in OSX El Capitan.

Answer (score 20):

You can use `arp-scan`.

Install using this command:

```
sudo apt-get install arp-scan
```

To list all IP addresses and associated MAC addresses, use:

```
sudo arp-scan --interface=eth0 --localnet
```

The output will look like this:

```
Interface: eth0, datalink type: EN10MB (Ethernet)
Starting arp-scan 1.8.1 with 16777216 hosts (http://www.nta-monitor.com/tools/arp-scan/)
192.168.1.3 38:60:77:29:31:36   (Unknown)
192.168.1.8 4c:72:b9:7c:bb:7e   (Unknown)
192.168.1.110   00:15:17:5f:d2:80   Intel Corporate
192.168.1.111   00:ff:88:5f:fd:f0   (Unknown)
192.168.1.153   00:15:17:5f:d2:82   Intel Corporate
192.168.1.180   52:54:00:70:04:02   QEMU
192.168.1.199   52:54:00:fe:7f:78   QEMU
```

Comment: This isn't finding a device that doesn't have an ip yet...

Answer (score 10):

### GUI

You can try [avahi-discover [image: Install avahi-discover]](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/avahi-discover).

1. Install it with this command (or by clicking the above link):

   ```
    sudo apt-get install avahi-discover
   ```
2. Run *Avahi Zeroconf Browser* or `avahi-discover` from a terminal.
3. You should see a window with a list of devices on your local network.
   The MAC address will be the string in the square brackets.

### Command line

You can use this command in a terminal:

```
avahi-browse -a -t -d local
```

It is installed by default.

Comment: Does this work to show the MAC address of a machine that is not running any services of any kind?

Comment: In my case this doesn't work for every device on the network. It's pretty damned neat, but it won't show dumb clients without avahi/upnp services.

Answer (score 5):

1. First do a scan of the network to see which hosts are reachable/online using `nmap -sn 1.2.3.4/24` or `fping -g 1.2.3.4/24`
2. Then query the MAC address corresponding to the IP address using `arping`. Pseudo-code ahead:

   ```
   for i in $(cat list-of-reachable-hosts)
   do 
       arping $i
   done
   ```
3. Cheatery: consult the arp-cache of your local switch; that should give you a nice overview...

Answer (score 4):

In cases that the [NetBIOS protocol](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NetBIOS) is supported, I prefer to use

`nbtscan 192.168.1.1-192.168.1.255`.

Comment: This only detects clients that support NetBIOS protocol (Windows and Linux+Samba).

Answer (score 3):

I was intrigued by this post. I've had the need for this.

I wrote a shell script that parses the `arp` output using `awk` statements and generates HTML output. If you execute the script and redirect the output to an HTML file, you are left with an HTML file that shows the IP, the full MAC address, and a link to the IEEE OUI lookup page. This helps in determining the client by way of NIC manufacturer.

```
printf "<html>\n<title>LAN IPs and their MACs</title>\n<body>\n"
arp -a | awk '{print $2,$4}' | awk -F'[().: ]' '{print $2"."$3"."$4"."$5,$6,$7":"$8":"$9":"$10":"$11":"$12,"<a href=\"http://standards.ieee.org/cgi-bin/ouisearch?"$7$8$9"\">IEEE OUI Lookup "$7"-"$8"-"$9"</a><br>"}'
printf "\n</body>\n</html>\n"
```

It helps to execute an `nmap` scan on your LAN first so you have entries in the ARP table.
Hopefully the formatting translated. You could spruce this up to have the text in a table format.

Answer (score 3):

After Some work and search I'v discovered this command:

```
nmap -sP -PE -PA21,23,80,3389 192.168.1.*
```

`nmap:` Network exploration tool and security / port scanner

`-sP` (Skip port scan) .
This option tells Nmap not to do a port scan after host discovery, and only print out the available
hosts that responded to the scan. This is often known as a “ping scan”, but you can also request that
    traceroute and NSE host scripts be run. This is by default one step more intrusive than the list
    scan, and can often be used for the same purposes. It allows light reconnaissance of a target network
    without attracting much attention. Knowing how many hosts are up is more valuable to attackers than
    the list provided by list scan of every single IP and host name.

`-PE; -PP; -PM (`ICMP Ping Types) .
    In addition to the unusual TCP, UDP and SCTP host discovery types discussed previously, Nmap can send
    the standard packets sent by the ubiquitous ping program. Nmap sends an ICMP type 8 (echo request)
    packet to the target IP addresses, expecting a type 0 (echo reply) in return from available hosts..
    Unfortunately for network explorers, many hosts and firewalls now block these packets, rather than
    responding as required by RFC 1122[2]. For this reason, ICMP-only scans are rarely reliable enough
    against unknown targets over the Internet. But for system administrators monitoring an internal
    network, they can be a practical and efficient approach. Use the -PE option to enable this echo
    request behavior.

`-A` (Aggressive scan options) .
    This option enables additional advanced and aggressive options.

`21,23,80,3389`  Ports to search through

`192.168.1.*`  Range of IPs. replace with yours

Answer (score 1):

After getting tired of using nmap and ARP combo, I created this small program which queries all MAC addresses for a given IP range: https://github.com/drkblog/findmacs

Answer (score 0):

On servers which do not include `arp` or `nmap` you can use `ip` to do this through the `neighbor` subcommand.

**NOTE:** To be clear, these are the machines that this machine is actively connecting with.

#### Usage

```
$ ip n help
Usage: ip neigh { add | del | change | replace }
                { ADDR [ lladdr LLADDR ] [ nud STATE ] | proxy ADDR } [ dev DEV ]
       ip neigh { show | flush } [ proxy ] [ to PREFIX ] [ dev DEV ] [ nud STATE ]
                                 [ vrf NAME ]

STATE := { permanent | noarp | stale | reachable | none |
           incomplete | delay | probe | failed }
```

#### Example

```
ip n | grep -i reach
192.168.13.152 dev storage lladdr 02:19:ff:74:af:85 REACHABLE
192.168.13.151 dev storage lladdr 02:18:ff:74:af:57 REACHABLE
192.168.3.129 dev rhevm lladdr 00:17:ff:00:01:7c REACHABLE
192.168.3.151 dev rhevm lladdr 52:54:16:ff:27:1e REACHABLE
192.168.13.150 dev storage lladdr 02:15:ff:b9:fa:f4 REACHABLE
192.168.13.149 dev storage lladdr 02:14:ff:b9:f9:ba REACHABLE
192.168.13.154 dev storage lladdr 02:13:ff:74:af:85 REACHABLE
192.168.3.152 dev rhevm lladdr 00:1a:12:ff:03:64 REACHABLE
```

#### References

- http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/ip-neighbour.8.html

Answer (score -1):

you can use `arp`.

This will show you the MAC and the IP's..