# Is it possible to connect remote system using mac-address?

Tags: remote-access

Is it possible to connect remote system using mac-address in Ubuntu? I don't want to use IP address. Both systems are in same LAN.

Comment: using what protocol?

Comment: using ssh @Maythux

Comment: Would you consider using the hostname instead of the MAC? you can "ssh username@hostname.local"

Comment: If you noticed, I'd said 'actually i want to do clean installation of ubuntu remotely. i read the answers but i am not getting the point of how to connect machine remotely and this is how i came to this question' @katutxakurra

Answer (score 8):

From [commlineFu](http://www.commandlinefu.com/commands/view/3447/connect-via-ssh-using-mac-address):

connect via ssh using mac address
Instead of looking for the right ip address, just pick whatever address you like and set a static ip mapping.

```
sudo arp -s 192.168.1.200  00:35:cf:56:b2:2g temp && ssh root@192.168.1.200
```

Another command:

```
ssh root@`for ((i=1; i<=255; i++));do arp -a 192.168.1.$i; done | grep 00:35:cf:56:b2:2g | awk '{print $2}' | sed -e 's/(//' -e 's/)//'`
```

then all you have to change the MAC and choose any IP you wish to use and change root to a valid user

*Note: Those commands is just a hack an in really they are using the IP itself not the MAC.*

**Example using second command:**

My LAN IP range is 10.1.1.* .The MAC of server want to connect to is 00:15:17:5f:XX:XX . The user on the host machine is called `maythux`

So the command will be:

```
ssh maythux@`for ((i=1; i<=20; i++));do arp -a 10.1.1.$i; done | grep 00:15:17:5f:XX:XX | awk '{print $2}' | sed -e 's/(//' -e 's/)//'`
```

Note i make for loop to 20 just for timing and i already know ip is less than 20, in case you dont range so keep it to 255.

And boom I'm prompted for password of user maythux in the host pc

---

**TIP:**

Instead you can normally use SSH with using IP, if you don't know the IP of some systems you can get it from the MAC, take a look for my question [List all MAC addresses and their associated IP addresses in my local network (LAN)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/406792/list-all-mac-addresses-and-their-associated-ip-addresses-in-my-local-network-lan) , you'll find many answers how to get an IP knowing its MAC

Comment: I am not getting anything with second command. maybe due to i don't have complete knowledge of ubuntu. still i will try. hope it will work @Maythux

Comment: I'll list down example wait me

Comment: actually i want to do clean installation of ubuntu remotely. i read the answers but i am not getting the point of how to connect machine remotely and this is how i came to this question.

Comment: How would i get ip address if i am going to  install os?

Comment: From MAc address, check the Tip in the asnwer

Answer (score 0):

Don't know what exactly is the use case of yours. You can try [this](https://sites.google.com/site/joergtinner/) link.
From the developer of the script,

Examples:

```
      mac2ip A1:B2:C3:D4:E5:F6 \"ssh root@IP\""
      mac2ip B2:C3:D4 \"vncviewer IP:1\""
      mac2ip A1:B2:C3:D4:E5:F6 \"krdc IP\""
      mac2ip x x (will give you a MAC list.)"
      "Note:     depends on ping, ifconfig and arp."
```

Comment: I think you have too many quotes, looks like you copy/pasted from the script. So for the 1st 3 commands, remove the last double quote. Also no need to escape the quotes that was just for the how to. It also appears you need to use lower case letters.