# How to find mac address of devices connected to my modem and block them from my network on ubuntu terminal?

Tags: networking, nmap

Firstly, I want to thank you as finally I found IP addresses that were connected to my modem. I found out all 5 devices that were connected to my modem using nmap, while it was showing only 2 devices before scanning. I want to find their mac address and remove those devices from my Wi-Fi using Gnome-Terminal. I am able to do this using modem interface but I want to work on Ubuntu and learn Linux, so I want to do this using Terminal. İs it possible? If yes, please tell me how?

Comment: possible duplicate of [List all MAC addresses and their associated IP addresses in my local network (LAN)](http://askubuntu.com/questions/406792/list-all-mac-addresses-and-their-associated-ip-addresses-in-my-local-network-la)

Comment: You can not "kick" them with pc from router. To find mac address on local lan you can use `nmap`, `arp-scan` ... but `wifi theft` connent to router and you must block them on router.

Comment: Finding out mac address is one step.  Second, step would be to set up mac filtering on your router. Third, change the wifi password. And finally set up admin password on the router itself

Comment: @Serg I know I have to mac filtering, change the wifi password. But I want to ask whole of these steps is that possible on linux terminal, because I try to learn linux. Thank you.

Comment: @m.tuğrul Well, you can find mac addresses through linux terminal with `nmap` like bodhi shows in his answer, but the wifi router is a different machine, and it may or may  not have linux firmware.

Comment: @Serg thank you for your interest. I already found their ip adresses via nmap but nmap didn't show their mac adresses. nmap showed my router mac adress but didn't show other devices'.

Answer (score 3):

You can use nmap with any of several options. The machines must be on the same LAN, no router in between.

- `nmap -sP`
- `nmap -sn`
- `nmap -sL`
- `nmap -PU`

See man nmap and / or: https://nmap.org/book/man-host-discovery.html

Comment: the use of `nmap` could be classified by administrators as an attack. Use the tool only in your network

Comment: thank you so much, I wanna ask you one more thing. How long nmap scan on your computer?

Comment: Depends on the quantity of systems in your network.

Answer (score 2):

If you are interested in using something other than `nmap`, there is also a tool called `tuxcut` that lets you scan and block other devices's MAC address connected to the same LAN as yours.
Find the tool [here](https://bitbucket.org/a_atalla/tuxcut/downloads).

Comment: Thank you, Is it work on ubuntu? Can we run it on terminal?

Comment: Yes it works on any Linux system. It actually comes with a Graphical User Interface so you wouldn't be needing to use the terminal.

Answer (score 2):

An alternative to `nmap` would be `arp-scan`. It's reasonably fast and does give mac addresses. The only limitation it has is that it is only for IPv4 addresses, but for a home network as in your case, this will be OK.

Sample output:

```
xieerqi:$ sudo arp-scan --interface=eth0 147.153.173.0/24   
Interface: eth0, datalink type: EN10MB (Ethernet)
Starting arp-scan 1.8.1 with 256 hosts (http://www.nta-monitor.com/tools/arp-scan/)
147.153.173.1   3c:df:1e:8c:ed:40   Cisco Systems
147.153.173.16  34:17:eb:c0:21:0f   (Unknown)
147.153.173.20  34:17:eb:c1:29:3e   (Unknown)
147.153.173.21  00:17:f2:05:cb:cc   Apple Computer
147.153.173.21  00:17:f2:05:cb:cc   Apple Computer (DUP: 2)
147.153.173.22  bc:30:5b:d8:9f:ea   Dell Inc.
147.153.173.23  00:22:19:2d:7b:33   Dell Inc
147.153.173.24  34:17:eb:c0:56:cb   (Unknown)
147.153.173.29  34:17:eb:c0:21:76   (Unknown)
```

Comment: thank you. which one is faster? nmap or arp?

Comment: @m.tuğrul definitely arp because it is a very simple scan